# Run a GUI OS via a hypervisor from a Linux server terminal?

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, gui, desktop-environment

Is there a way to run a VM hypervisor, such as VirtualBox directly, from say, CentOS? Let's suppose that I want a high-efficiency server, but it can host guests with GUI-enabled OS's. Additionally, this can be booted directly via a terminal in a non GUI-enabled Linux distro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into using a VM Hypervisor like KVM or Xen.  KVM is built into the Linux kernel (and Xen is scheduled to be at sometime in the future).  You can manage KVM using a tool like virt-manager.